# Unable to access hosts using rest assured framework

Tags: java, rest-assured, hosts

As per my API testing, I had to first login to two ssh hosts through terminal(mac machine) then we use  curl command for requests. I am asked to automate this using RestAssured.

To login hosts, I have used jcraft.jsch.JSch java library which i am able to access to hosts successfully but after this when I use below rest assured code, I am getting error "Connection refused"

```
Response response = RestAssured.given().header(<header>).body(<payload>).relaxedHTTPSValidation().when().post(<url>);
```

Is there any way to connect ssh hosts through Rest Assured framework or any other solution ? Please help.

Comment: Where do you run your rest assured code?

Comment: In Eclipse, TestNg, Rest Assured and java combination

Comment: I mean from which host do you made you RestAssured requests? And do you use ssh port forwarding?

Comment: Yes i used ssh port forwarding with the jsch library.

Comment: Do we have any methods in Rest Assured for ssh port forwarding ?